# How to set the collection name in Mongoid for a subclass?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

```
class Foo
  include Mongoid::Document
end

class Bar < Foo
end
```

Foo.all returns Bars, and Bar.all returns Foos.

I want to put Foo and Bar in separate collections.

I tried

```
class Bar < Foo
  store_in collection: 'bars'
```

but got

```
Mongoid::Errors::InvalidStorageParent:
Problem:
  Invalid store_in call on class Bar.
Summary:
  The :store_in macro can only be called on a base Mongoid Document
```

Using Mongoid 4.0.2

Answer (score 14):

You need to make `Bar` a `Mongoid` document as well.

```
class Bar < Foo
  include Mongoid::Document
  store_in collection: 'bars'
```

Comment: I should have tried that. I read this https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1133#issuecomment-1767252 and it suggests that you can't do it this way...

Comment: For me this is not working on Mongoid 4.0.2. Still same error.

Comment: This is not working for me as well

Comment: Doesn't work with mongoid 6

Comment: @B Seven the link is dead

Answer (score 1):

This question is very old now but Mongoid now supports it out of the box.

Previously, you would have to make a module with all the common logic and include them in both the Model Classes.

From Mongoid v8.1 onwards, you can use `store_in collection: "collection_name` for this.

```rb
class Shape
  include Mongoid::Document
  store_in collection: :shapes
end

class Circle < Shape
  store_in collection: :circles
end
```

This will create the documents in 2 different collections (shapes and circles).

Reference: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongoid/current/reference/inheritance/#persistence-contexts